# Call to undefined method stdClass::links()

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I am sending a request to a web API, which responses with an encoded paginated response, I am receiving the response and decoding it successfully. The response looks like the following:

```
{#225 ▼
  +"message": "تم بنجاح"
  +"code": "1"
  +"data": {#220 ▼
    +"current_page": 1
    +"data": array:10 [▶]
    +"from": 1
    +"last_page": 2
    +"next_page_url": "http://localhost:8000/api/getpostsadmin?page=2"
    +"path": "http://localhost:8000/api/getpostsadmin"
    +"per_page": 10
    +"prev_page_url": -1
    +"to": 10
    +"total": 11
  }
}
```

Bellow is a part of the controller code:

```
  if ($response->code=='1')
            {
//                dd($response->data);
                $data=$response->data;

//
//                dd($data);
                 return view('posts',compact('data'));
            }
```

and here is the view code:

```
 <div class="table-responsive">
                    <table class="table table-bordered" id="dataTable" width="100%" cellspacing="0">
                        <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>ID</th>
                            <th>Title AR</th>
                            <th>Title EN</th>
                            <th>Description AR</th>
                            <th>Description EN</th>
                            <th>Created At</th>
                        </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tfoot>
                        <tr>
                            <th>ID</th>
                            <th>Title AR</th>
                            <th>Title EN</th>
                            <th>Description AR</th>
                            <th>Description EN</th>
                            <th>Created At</th>
                        </tr>
                        </tfoot>
                        <tbody>
                        @foreach($data->data as $datum)
                        <tr>
                            <td>{{$datum->id}}</td>
                            <td>{{$datum->title_ar}}</td>
                            <td>{{$datum->title_en}}</td>
                            <td>{{$datum->description_ar}}</td>
                            <td>{{$datum->description_en}}</td>
                            <td>{{$datum->created_at}}</td>
                        </tr>
                        @endforeach



                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                    {!! $data->links() !!}
                </div>
```

Why this error is always appearing?
I tried `render()` method instead and  `{!! $data->data->links() !!}`,
but nothing worked.

The API code that returns the response is:

```
$post=post::orderBy('created_at','asc')->paginate(10); $post=$post->toArray(); $post=public_functions::remove_nulls($post); 
return response()>json(["message"=>"success","code"=>'1','data'=>$post]);
```

Comment: use paginate method

Comment: in the api i am using paginate!

Comment: you said render method right?

Comment: "Call to undefined method stdClass::paginate()" this error is shown

Comment: please use `paginate(10)` to get 10 items per page

Comment: for the data variable?

Comment: No where you used paginate now use paginate(10) and try

Comment: still not working

Comment: No, where you are using render method.

Comment: can you copy your paginate section codes here?

Comment: `$items->orderBy('site.site')->orderBy('states.name')->orderBy('zones.name')
                    ->paginate(10);`

Comment: just post your `$response` on your question as edit

Comment: the response is the first code block 
the query of pagination in the api is :
  $post=post::orderBy('created_at','asc')->paginate(10);
 $post=$post->toArray();
                    $post=public_functions::remove_nulls($post);
return response()->json(["message"=>"success","code"=>'1','data'=>$post]);

Comment: there is 3 post variables i am seeing. i believe its not the first post that is getting returned. please check that

Comment: first I am getting the response then i'm transforming it to an array to remove the nulls then i am getting the final result and encoding it

Comment: You mentioned in the question that you get an error. Which error exactly? I

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if you're still having issues, but you're using

```
$post = post::orderBy('created_at','asc')->paginate(10);
```

followed immediately by

```
$post = $post->toArray();
```

and lastly

```
return response()>json([
  "message" => "success",
  "code" => "1",
  "data" => $post
]);
```

There is a method `->links()` that's available on the result of `->paginate()`, but not once you use `->toArray()`, and *definitely not* once you cast it to `json` via `response()->json()`.

If you want `->links()` available in your `json` response, you need to attach it prior to converting and casting, or set as a new variable:

```
$post = post::orderBy('created_at','asc')->paginate(10);
$links = $post->links();
$post = $post->toArray();
$post["links"] = $links;

return response()>json([
  "message" => "success",
  "code" => "1",
  "data" => $post
]);
```

In that case, you *should* be able to call `{!! $data->links !!}` in your view and properly render your pagination links. Just be aware of what `$post` is and why functions won't work on it.